# Make the spin program repeat?

Tags: java

```
   public static void main (String[] args) {

        int input = 0;


        // Creating our objects
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Math math = new Math();

        System.out.println("Welcome to Spin Game!");
        System.out.println("Please write '1' to spin, or -1 to exit.");

        //The input the user wrote..
        input = console.nextInt();

        if (input == 1) {

            int number = math.calculate(math.number());

            if (number < 30)
            {
                System.out.println("You just won the game!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lost..");                   
            }
        }
    }
```

**What:**

Basically spin game, if number is below 30, you won, else, you lose.
What I want is, the problem to continue. Onc eyou write '1', it will tell you if you've lost or won, and then let's you play again, without ending the program.

**Problem:**

The program just exists after writing '1'.
And I can't play again unless I re-start the program.

***Why is it doing that?***

I am new to Java.

Comment: if(...) is not for loop. I think you are looking for while(...)

Comment: I know that, but do I need a loop for that?, If I use a loop, it repeats: You lost..
"You lost.." forever..

Comment: Well if you want repeat, you do need loop, isn't it?

Comment: But it repeats the results forever without stopping

Comment: It is surprising that without loop it is repeating forever. In generally forever loops (infinite loops) occur when expression in loop never satisfies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change it to this:

```
   public static void main (String[] args) {

        int input = 0;


        // Creating our objects
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Math math = new Math();

        System.out.println("Welcome to Spin Game!");
        System.out.println("Please write '1' to spin, or -1 to exit.");

        //The input the user wrote..

        input = console.nextInt();

        while(input == 1) {                
            int number = math.calculate(math.number());

            if (number < 30)
            {
                System.out.println("You just won the game!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lost..");                   
            }
            input = console.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

This will loop the process!

1. First input is set to 0.
2. Then it asks you what you want to do (set input to 1 or -1).
3. If you set it to 1, the program will enter the loop and run it once. At the end of the loop it will again ask you what you want to do (1 or -1).
4. If input is 1, the loop will run again. Then it goes like this. If you want you could add a `System.out.println("Please write '1' to spin, or -1 to exit.");` right after `input = console.nextInt();` in the loop. This will make the text appear every loop.

Comment: Some explanatory text would help the answer

Comment: Explanatory text added. Hope this helps =). Please ask if you don't understand something.

Answer (score 1):

I've posted working code below. The solution is, that you want the program to repeatedly execute until the user enters the number: -1. So, while input does not equal -1, we want the program to go ahead and run. Now obviously, we want it to run at least once, and since we initialize the value of `input=0;`, we don't have to worry because it will definitely enter the while loop the first time. Now, if the user enters -1, it will hit your `if(input==1)` and evaluate to false, and therefore check the `while(input != -1)` condition again, which will this time return false (because it does equal) and the loop will break and end the application.

```
public static void main (String[] args) {

    int input = 0;


    // Creating our objects
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Math math = new Math();

    while(input != -1)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to Spin Game!");
        System.out.println("Please write '1' to spin, or -1 to exit.");

        //The input the user wrote..
        input = console.nextInt();

        if (input == 1) {

            int number = math.calculate(math.number());

            if (number < 30)
            {
                System.out.println("You just won the game!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lost..");                   
            }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Some explanatory text would help the answer

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a while loop.

I also added logic to check other input values. Adding validation to other input values will help catch any logic errors that may occur. Without adding it, your program will loop on **any** input value, not just `1`.

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {

        int input = 0;


        // Creating our objects
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        Math math = new Math();

        System.out.println("Welcome to Spin Game!");
        System.out.println("Please write '1' to spin, or -1 to exit.");

        while(true){ //Infinite loop, i.e. execute until condition is false.         
          //The input the user wrote..
          input = console.nextInt();

            if (input == 1) {

            int number = math.calculate(math.number());

            if (number < 30)
                {
                     System.out.println("You just won the game!");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You lost..");                   
                }
            } else if (input == -1){
                break; //exit the loop, alternatively, add some exit text here 
            } else {
               System.out.println("Please Enter 1 to spin, or -1 to exit.");               
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why have a `break;` case. That's redundant.

Comment: I am not looping on input, I loop on `1`.

Comment: Well, that's not a good idea either. Why obscure things and use 1?(boolean -> int) conversions are not identical across all languages and just serves for messier code. why not use true?

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{

    int input = 0;


    // Creating our objects
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System. in );
    Math math = new Math();

    System.out.println("Welcome to Spin Game!");
    System.out.println("Please write '1' to spin, or -1 to exit.");

    //The input the user wrote..
    input = console.nextInt();

    boolean running = true;

    while (running)
    {

        if (input == 1)
        {

            int number = math.calculate(math.number());

            if (number < 30)
            {
                System.out.println("You just won the game!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You lost..");
            }
        }
        else if (input == -1)
        {
            running = false;
        }
    }
}
```

What I did is added a new boolean variable and in a while loop, I'm running the spin game code. When the input is -1, the variable running is set to false and the game terminates.